# Mapping a Wikimedia project URL to the corresponding Wikidata entity id

Tags: wikidata

I am looking for the best method to map a given Wikipedia/Wikisource/Wikibooks/... URL to the corresponding Wikidata entity id (similar to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5467/mapping-wikipedia-urls-to-wikidata-urls) but via API calls instead of a full data dump). The URL can be in many forms, e.g.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Element_18 is redirected (HTTP) to
- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Element_18 is redirected (HTTP) to
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_18 is redirected (JavaScript/HTML) to
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon

Methods I tried so far:

- SPARQL query service - requires the URL to have a canonical form and seems to not know about redirects
- MediaWiki API at Wikidata, e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwiki&titles=Argon&languages=en&props=labels|descriptions&format=jsonfm requires to securely split URL into title and "site" key
- MediaWiki API at project site, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&titles=Argon requires to securely split URL into project and title
- Info page, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Argon&action=info requires to modify URL and to parse resulting HTML

The most reliable (but nasty) method seems to enulate a browser to do a HTTP request to the URL, follow all redirects and parse the resulting HTML page to get the Wikidata ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, Wikidata won't know about redirects - they're not part of the model there. They only record the canonical page title (leaving aside a few rare cases where the Wikidata sitelink *is* a redirect, which is deprecated but does occasionally happen). So any 'de-redirecting' will need to be done on the Wikipedia side.

If you use the local API with `&redirects`, you can get the Wikidata entity ID in a single query whether or not there's a redirect -

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&titles=Element_18&redirects`

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&titles=Argon&redirects`

both contain `"wikibase_item": "Q696"`

You'll still have to process the URL a bit to get the API call, though.

Comment: Thanks! I Implemented this method in [my Wikidata command line client](https://github.com/nichtich/wdq#readme) version 0.3.5. URL preprocessing also detects percent-encoding etc.